# Multi assignment using objects

Tags: java, object, queue, variable-assignment

I am implementing a simple Queue Class for my programming class.

Java assigns values from right to left, does that still apply to objects?

I was hoping to cut out the use of a placeholder variable with something like this:

```
public void enqueue(int i)
{
    lastNode = lastNode.next = new Node();
    lastNode.value = i;

}
```

Will that work? And/or should I just use a placeholder variable for readability?

Comment: I'd recommend using a variable for readability, but of course you could always try this yourself and see.

Comment: The line you wrote will leave other programmers scratching their heads.  If I read it, I'd have to go dig through the JLS to figure out what the semantics are, or write a test program to try it, since I don't know offhand how this would work.  All that hassle so you could save about 30 keystrokes.  **Please, please, please, do not try to be clever!**  It is _much_ more important to be straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

This will work iff

- the variable 'lastNode' is already initialized
- 'lastNode' is not null, otherwise you have a Null Pointer for lastNode.next

Please don't do this, it does not make much sense just because you want to cut out a placeholder variable.